# Getting Uncaught ReferenceError: auth is not defined error but it is already defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

A weird issue I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: auth is not defined at auth.js:2` But I am sure It is already defined in index.html because SignUp and Login is working perfectly. But still its showing error in AuthState. What is wrong with this code?

```
// AuthState
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    console.log('user logged in: ', user);
  } else {
    console.log('user logged out');
  }
});

// Signup
const signupForm = document.querySelector('#signupForm');

if(signupForm)
{
  signupForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const email = signupForm['signupemail'].value;
    const password = signupForm['signuppassword'].value;

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
      console.log(cred.user);
      signupForm.reset();
    });
  });
}

// Login
const loginForm = document.querySelector('#loginForm');

if(loginForm)
{
  loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const email = loginForm['loginemail'].value;
    const password = loginForm['loginpassword'].value;

    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((cred) => {
      console.log(cred.user);
      loginForm.reset();
    });
  });
}
```

This is the index.html page code I put this code bottom of the body section.

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/auth.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "x:xxxxxxx:xxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "G-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();

  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const db = firebase.firestore();
</script>
```

So, above is the code ......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: If you're getting the error, then your assumption is wrong. How exactly is `auth` defined? Nothing you posted explains that.

Comment: Ok, My point is if Auth is defined incorrect then why Login and Signup is working fine?

Comment: When are you getting this error and where is `auth` imported ?

Comment: Your code refers to `auth` outside of any function, so it has to be defined at the point the script is initially interpreted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that you are importing the script before you define the variable.

It should be

```
<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "x:xxxxxxx:xxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "G-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();

  const auth = firebase.auth(); // <----- this is where you define auth
  const db = firebase.firestore();
</script>
<script src="scripts/auth.js"></script> <!-- then you import the script -->
```

So first you define auth, then you import the script that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyDBrgamDSO-o-3Pr_yRILe1ohsKRscxFK4",
        authDomain: "auth-thenetninja-8c561.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://auth-thenetninja-8c561.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "auth-thenetninja-8c561",
        storageBucket: "auth-thenetninja-8c561.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "807934937683",
        appId: "1:807934937683:web:5a0676e96cb8c4cb2cd4a6"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    // Make auth and firestore references
    const auth = firebase.auth()
    const db = firebase.firestore()
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/auth.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add some description to let us know what was causing that error.