# Firebase authentication error in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm encountering an error when trying to add a user to firebase authentication. The const auth is defined before the script is loaded. I've tried calling with and without the app parameter. The user is not being added and I can't seem to figure this error out. I've cut out only the code I think is relevant. Apologies if this is a stupid question, I'm just diving into HTML and JS.

> Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: auth is not defined
>
> at HTMLFormElement. (auth.js:12)

From html file:

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-auth.js";
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app.js";
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
<script src="js\auth.js"></script>
```

From js file:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
        console.log(cred);
    });
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61545170/getting-uncaught-referenceerror-auth-is-not-defined-error-but-it-is-already-def) might help.

Comment: Hey Rob, Thanks for looking into this. I actually found that post via searching earlier but it seems like the solution they recommend is that the auth must be declared before the script is imported which I believe is how mine is already set up unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the modular SDK, which means that imported names are no longer added to a global namespace. If your include file (`js.auth.js`) needs access to the `auth` service, you will need to import `getAuth` into that file too and initialize it there as well.

Comment: This was the solution! For any others who might come across this, I had to mark the js import in the html as script type module and then import the names(?) into the js file as well. Also it's not 'auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)' it's 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)'. Thanks a bunch for the help Frank!